# debug SLOW jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I have the following jQuery code that I use to hide/show options in a select based on if they have a active=F or active=T custom attribute.  It works great, however when the select contains a lot of options, it takes 10 seconds or more sometimes to finish and causes the page to lock up.  Would anyone have any pointers how I could optimize this code?

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).toggle(show);
                if(show){
                    if($(this).parent('span.toggleOption').length) $(this).unwrap();
                    $('#unitsSelector').val(""); 
                } else {
                    $(this).wrap('<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />');
                    $('#unitsSelector').val("");
                }
            });
        };
        var list = $('#unitsSelector option'), buttons = $('.unitToggle');
        list.toggleOption(false);
        buttons.on('click', function () {
            var filter = $(this).hasClass('active') ? "[active=F]" : "[active=T]";
            list.toggleOption(true).filter(filter).toggleOption(false);
        });
        $('.active').click();
    });
```

Thank you!!!

**UPDATE**

Fiddle available here

http://jsfiddle.net/L94Bz/

you'll notice when switching from active/inactive it takes quite a few seconds to complete.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to this. I have a similar problem bluring 5 input fields, takes like 3 seconds! Have you tried e.stopPropagation(); by the way? Could be bubbling up?

Comment: I have not tried e.stopPropagation(), am not familiar with it.  Looking into it now though.

Comment: I think. $(document).ready(function(e) {  e.stopPropagation();} it can sometimes cause some unexpected behaviour, so double check functionality if it works.

Comment: You mean besides where you call `$(this)` 4 times in the same function instead of storing it as a local variable and re-using it?

Comment: Can you set up an example fiddle where this is reproducable?

Comment: What @JoeSimmons said. Also, there's no way to tell how many elements you're running this on. Poorly optimized code magnifies latency over larger data sets.

Comment: @JoeSimmons, I realize this is a large request, but any chance of an example of how to apply event delegation?  I'm completely new to it.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code more closely, event delegation isn't your problem at all. Your problem is simply that you're looping over so many elements. Your goal here would be to find a way to do as few loops as possible. - Also, event delegation info can be found at the bottom of my answer on this page.

Comment: Is wrapping an `option` in a `span` even valid html?

Comment: Can we have a chat 1 on 1? I need to know exactly what you want this code to do, in theory. If it's just hiding every other number when you click "Inactive", then I can optimize your code **A TON**.

Comment: @JasonP: Turns out, yes. lol.

Comment: @JoeSimmons, all I need is to have all options with the active="F" not display when the user has "active" selected, and the same for when the user has inactive selected, hide all with active="T".

Comment: @Phil Give this a try... I removed the wrapping/unwrapping, but the options hide and show, and it's a whole lot faster. http://jsfiddle.net/MTn8p/

Comment: @Phil: You did it backwards, lol. But much faster, indeed.

Comment: @JasonP, yes your method is faster, but if you try it in Chrome you'll see it causes issues with the way the items in the select are displayed when Inactive is selected.  I had this problem in the beginning which is why I wrapped it in a span element.

Comment: @Phil What issues? I'm using Chrome 29, and don't see anything wrong.

Comment: For me the options under the select only show the first one, and has a vertical scroll bar that I have to scroll through to see other items.  In other words the dropdown is squished to a very small height.  Maybe it's something else causing that.  Will look into it.  Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: You can do this without JavaScript, and it's infinitely faster and simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/7SQMM/  Lesson learned: do what you can with HTML/CSS before you resort to JavaScript.

Comment: @JoeSimmons, I'm not hiding/showing even or odd items, it's based on if the option has a active attribute of "T" or "F".  These attributes are created when the page is rendered with php based on what the value is coming from the database.

Comment: Well you can do that with CSS, too. It's even easier. Don't you know CSS?

Comment: Here's another example, with your attributes: http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/ZetBU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cache those `$(...)` calls in variables, first off.

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var list = $('#unitsSelector option'),
        unitsSelector = $('#unitsSelector');

    $.fn.toggleOption = function (show) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.toggle(show);

            if (show && $this.parent('span.toggleOption').length) {
                $this.unwrap();
            } else {
                $this.wrap('<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />');
            }

            unitsSelector.val("");
        });
    };

    list.toggleOption(false);

    $('.unitToggle').on('click', function () {
        var filter = $(this).hasClass('active') ? "[active=F]" : "[active=T]";
        list.toggleOption(true).filter(filter).toggleOption(false);
    });

    $('.active').click();

});
```

---

You should also use [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) via [jQuery](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/).

If I knew your html, or had a working fiddle example, I could help you a lot more.

Comment: @JoeSimmons, any chance of a short example of how I could apply event delegation?  I'm completely new to it.

Comment: Examples in those links at the end there.

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix: quit rerunning jQuery constructors throughout the loop.  Every time you say something like `$(#unitsSelector)`, work's going on behind the scenes.

```
$.fn.toggleOption = function( show ) {
  var $units = $('#unitsSelector'); 

  return this.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggle(show);
    if(show){
      if($this.parent('span.toggleOption').length) $this.unwrap();
      $units.val(""); 
    } else {
      $this.wrap('<span class="toggleOption" style="display: none;" />');
      $units.val("");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Actually, jQuery selectors are heavily cached, intelligent enough not to re-select when in a loop.

Comment: Not always true when (as here) dom modifications are going on during the loop.